# Replace link with hash using id in link

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace an id in a link with a generated value, using that specific id. For example I have a string which (might) contain links:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
http://www.example.com/file/1

Curabitur volutpat nulla purus, vitae pharetra diam commodo porttitor
http://www.example.com/file/2
```

I want to replace both id's with a function, in which I change the results depending on the page they're on (in this case, unique links on each page to the same file). I think I need a [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), but how do I pass the id to the replacement function as a variable?

For example, something like (psuedo code):

```
function hash_it($file_id, $page_id) {
     return md5($file_id . $page_id);
}
$page_id = 1;
$text = preg_replace('"\b(http://www.example.com/file/\d+)"', hash_it($1, $page_id), $text);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a callback to replace your data, then use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\b(http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/file\/\d+)/', 'hash_it', $text);
```

-you should not forget regex delimiters also (they should be non-aplphanumeric in PHP, in my sample it's `/`). And, of course, escape special regex symbols like `.`

Now, about your callback: it will work with full matched data array, not like you've defined (separate arguments) - see manual page for samples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't know about the preg_replace_callback() function. But... how do I pass the id to the function?

Comment: @Wietse as I've said, see manual page for samples. If you want to get it inside matches array in your callback, you'll have to group it in your regex with `()`

Comment: Yep, this is what I need! The variable $matches[2] gives me what I need: the id. Thanks!